# VS Code Error: (this.configurationService.getValue(...) || []).filter is not a function

Tags: python, json, debugging, visual-studio-code

I just started getting this error in VS Code that prevents me from create a new file or even opening a file. The pop error that VS Code shows is `(this.configurationService.getValue(...) || []).filter is not a function`

This error/bug even stops me from opening the extensions tab or launching basic hotkeys. Anybody else have this issue?

Comment: use the debugger to find out what `this.configurationService.getValue(…)` returns

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I had the same problem.

Found few errors in settings.json. Try to check it and let me know how it will go.

This error pops up every time I try to create a new file saying

> "(this.configurationService.getValue(...) || []).filter is not a
> function"

In my case, I had to fix "workbench.editorAssociations" flag to:

```
"workbench.editorAssociations": [
    {
        "viewType": "jupyter-notebook",
        "filenamePattern": "*.ipynb"
    }
],
```

Previously it was:

```
"workbench.editorAssociations": {
    "*.ipynb": "jupyter-notebook"
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can't believe it. VS Code wasn't working on one system but not on the other and I was so damn confused. I had this config months ago and it haunted me now. Wasn't even able to open the hecking extensions.

Comment: settings.json keeps resetting every time i reboot the machine if you can help with that too

Comment: I had a few errors in my settings.json, all of which I fixed. But it appears, among them, I had the very same configuration for "workbench.editorAssociations" as yours. I think  jupyter notebooks broke something recently and fixing only this one may have been enough...

Answer (score 8):

I figured out the issue in the error is coming from the settings.json for VS Code (found here for mac `~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`). There was an extension that updated got updated with a bug. My particular one seems like it came from this line:

`"workbench.editorAssociations": { "*.ipynb": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb" }`

Anyways, hope this is helpful for someone in the future!

Comment: Replacing the flag from [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/ndjjjy/cant_create_new_file_nor_open_new_file_in_vscode/) also resolved the problem – it looks like settings sync between the stable and insiders edition also contributed to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me after I synced my settings between Visual Studio Code (the stable version) and "Visual Studio Code - Insiders".

For me, this error prevented Jupyter notebooks to be opened in Visual Studio Code.

Replacing the Jupyter notebook setting as suggested by [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67587398/vs-code-error-this-configurationservice-getvalue-filter-is-not-a-f#comment119601909_67587399) and implied by its above answer did not work for me.

What worked for me was to delete all Jupyter related entries in settings.json.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, where the `jupyter-notebook` extension was updated and caused a bug.

In the settings navigate to `"workbench.editorAssociations"`,

replace

```
 "*.ipynb": "jupyter-notebook"
```

with

```
 "viewType": "jupyter-notebook",
 "filenamePattern": "*.ipynb"
```

and everything will work fine.

For the settings file,

> By default VS Code shows the Settings editor, but you can still edit
> the underlying settings.json file by using the Open Settings (JSON)
> command or by changing your default settings editor with the
> workbench.settings.editor setting.
>
> Depending on your platform, the user settings file is located here:
>
> Windows   %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json
>
> macOS   $HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json
>
> Linux   $HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json

Answer (score 0):

##### Error `"(this.configurationService.getValue(...) || []).filter is not a function"` in Windows in Vscode

##### TL:DR;

**Remove** `"workbench.editorAssociations": { "*.ipynb": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb" }` in `Windows` from settings.json (In `Linux` Ubuntu it works though, you can leave it as is).

- Same solution as others here say
- Down the road: I use both environments and `git version` the `settings.json`, so I better remove it to avoid the error and be able to read files.
- Linux is the reason for the error in Windows.