# VSCode wan't open any existing file in the files explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

I waked up today and I can't open files in *VSCode*!

I'm clicking on files in the *VSCode Files Explorer* and nothing happened. But the files from previous work are still opened.

Also, trying to navigate to `Go To Definition` and things like that are not working. No new files opened.

Opening file by Right-Click and select `Open With... -> Text Editor` is working.

Comment: I accidentally turned off the FTP Simple extension along with several other extensions while trying to get rid of the pop up suggestions... With that turned off I could still see my directory of files but not edit them... duh

Comment: I get this from time to time. Completely bizarre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in one of the Python extensions.

From [this result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67587399/839513):

> I figured out the issue in the error is coming from the settings.json for VS Code (found here for mac `~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`). There was an extension that updated got updated with a bug. My particular one seems like it came from this line:
>
> `"workbench.editorAssociations": { "*.ipynb": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb" }`
>
> Anyways, hope this is helpful for someone in the future!

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue.  I just deleted all the cached files here:

`rm -rf /Users/<user>/Library/Application\ Support/Code`